# toggling div and adding and removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some divs i wanna toggle i am able to toggle but unable to remove classes when ever i click on the next div

**index.php**

```
<div id="menu_top1" class="menu_top1">LINK 1</div>
<div id="menu_top" class="menu_top">LINK 2</div>
<div id="content_area1" style="display:none;">
  THIS IS LINK 1
</div>
<div id="content_area2" style="display:none;">
  THIS IS LINK 2
</div>
```

**Jquery.js**

```
$('#menu_top1').click(function() {

  $('#content_area1').toggle('slow', function() {
    $('.menu_top1').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Here is a Fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/kunz/t5u6mcmn/

Comment: where is you click event for next div?

Comment: 'when ever i click on the next div' what div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to show corresponding content_area when you click on link and make the link active? you can check this 
[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ypye7rpg/)

i saw you using same id for multiple elements.just edited them.

still you want same id for all elements(strictly not recommended) check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t2r352wn/)

Comment: this is working fine thanks a lot but can you please explain me the jquery part from the first `fiddle` please it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check this updated [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t5u6mcmn/2/)

```
$('.menu_top').click(function() {
  var index = $( this ).index() + 1;
  console.log(index);
  $('[id^="content_area"]' ).hide();
  $('#content_area' + index ).toggle('slow', function() {
    $('.menu_top').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: If I understand OP, they simply want the current active link (if any) to become inactive if the user clicks one of the other links.

Comment: @BauceLawyerson that is happening, please check the working fiddle.